# Broken pysftp 'crypto_box_seedbytes'

Tags: python-3.x, pysftp

Today my scripts using pysftp are giving me this error:

```
File "teleres_ftpexport.py", line 2, in <module>
      import pysftp
    File "/home/pierrot/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
      import paramiko
    File "/home/pierrot/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
      from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
    File "/home/pierrot/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 57, in <module>
      from paramiko.ed25519key import Ed25519Key
    File "/home/pierrot/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/ed25519key.py", line 22, in <module>
      import nacl.signing
    File "/home/pierrot/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nacl/signing.py", line 19, in <module>
      import nacl.bindings
    File "/home/pierrot/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nacl/bindings/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
      from nacl.bindings.crypto_box import (
    File "/home/pierrot/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nacl/bindings/crypto_box.py", line 27, in <module>
      crypto_box_SEEDBYTES = lib.crypto_box_seedbytes()
    AttributeError: cffi library '_sodium' has no function, constant or global variable named 'crypto_box_seedbytes'
```

I tryed removing/reinstalling pysftp with

```
pip3 uninstall pysftp
pip3 install pysftp
```

But I still get that error message. I think the message is coming from paramiko (removing it didn't help). Any ideas how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

yup, paramiko
Once you get this sorted, then pysftp (which is a wrapper over paramiko) will install.